# a way of dealing with retina images in html

Tags: html, css, retina-display

i hope this is not a lame question because i dont have experience dealing with retina in html / css but i want to ask this: is it a good idea if i do something like this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    if (window.devicePixelRatio > 1) {

        $('body').addClass('retina');
    }
});
```

Practically if the screen is retina, i add a class retian on the body tag so in css i coudl write:

```
img {
    background: url(images/myimg.jpg);
}
.retina img {
    background: url(images/myimg@2x.jpg);
}
```

I hope if i'm not doing it right someone can explain me why. Thanks in advance for the feedback.

Comment: great information [on this site](http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-retina-graphics-for-your-web-designs)

Answer (score 0):

That's a fine idea, but not necessarily the standard right now. CSS has it's own capability to recognize retina screens using media queries. I'd recommend

```
img {
  background: url(images/myimg.jpg);
}

@media print,
(-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 5/4),
(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25),
(min-resolution: 120dpi) {
  img {
    background: url(images/myimg@2x.jpg);
  }
}
```

Comment: That media query can be moved to the end of your css file, or into a separate one if you'd like, and all your retina declarations can go in there. Or, if you use SASS, you can create a mixin and later use it like: `@inlude retina { ... }`

Comment: Hello @Pacuraru Daniel! Just wanted to check in with this. My answer above is definitely standard for retina images in CSS. Did it help you out at all? Was there any trouble? Also, if it was a satisfactory answer, would you mind accepting it as so?